# Using httr to place orders through BitMex API

Tags: r, api, httr, bitmex

I'm trying to use the httr R package to place orders on BitMex through their API.

I found some guidance over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53916713/api-post-with-authentication-in-r), and after specifying both my API key and secret in respectively the objects K and S, I've tried the following

```
verb <- 'POST'
expires <- floor(as.numeric(Sys.time() + 10000))
path <- '/api/v1/order'
data <- '{"symbol":"XBTUSD","price":4500,"orderQty":10}'

body <- paste0(verb, path, expires, data)
signature <- hmac(S, body, algo = 'sha256')

body_l <- list(verb = verb, expires = expires, path = path, data = data)
```

And then both:

```
msg <- POST('https://www.bitmex.com/api/v1/order', encode = 'json', body = body_l, add_headers('api-key' = K, 'api-signature' = signature, 'api-expires' = expires))
```

and:

```
msg <- POST('https://www.bitmex.com/api/v1/order', body = body, add_headers('api-key' = K, 'api-signature' = signature, 'api-expires' = expires))
```

Give me the same error message when checked:

```
rawToChar(msg$content)
[1] "{\"error\":{\"message\":\"Signature not valid.\",\"name\":\"HTTPError\"}}"
```

I've tried to set it up according to how [BitMex explains to use their API](https://www.bitmex.com/app/apiKeysUsage), but I appear to be missing something. They list out a couple of issues that might underly my invalid signature issue, but they don't seem to help me out. When following their example I get the exact same hashes, so that seems to be in order.

Comment: From my reading of the documentation, it should be `encode = 'form', body = data` in the `POST()` call. I have no way to test that though.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help; I got the same error. Thanks though!

Comment: You were right though, @MrFlick. It does read like that, but then still it doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Did you manage to fix the issue? I'm currently stuck at the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

bit late to the party here but hopefully this helps!

Your POST call just needs some minor changes:

- add `content_type_json()`
- include `.headers = c('the headers')` in `add_headers()`. See example below:

```
library(httr)
library(digest)

S <- "your api secret"
K <- "your api key"

verb <- 'POST'
expires <- floor(as.numeric(Sys.time() + 10))
path <- '/api/v1/order'
data <- '{"symbol":"XBTUSD","price":4500,"orderQty":10}'

body <- paste0(verb, path, expires, data)
signature <- hmac(S, body, algo = 'sha256')

msg <- POST('https://www.bitmex.com/api/v1/order', 
            encode = 'json', 
            body = data, 
            content_type_json(),
            add_headers(.headers = c('api-key' = K, 
                        'api-signature' = signature, 
                        'api-expires' = expires)))

content(msg, "text")
```

I have a package on CRAN - [bitmexr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bitmexr/index.html) - that provides a wrapper around the majority of BitMEX's API endpoints that you might be interested in. Still quite a "young" package so I would welcome any feedback!